# Meteor MUP PhantomJS error

Tags: meteor, phantomjs, mup

I'm using mup to deploy the Meteor app:

- docker Image : abernix/meteord:base
- using ongoworks:spiderable for phantomjs / docker compatibility

Spiderable works fine in local development environment.

I am getting error when trying to

$curl http://hostname?_escaped_fragment_=

Internal Server Error

And, in mup logs, I see this:

`spiderable: phantomjs failed: Error: Command failed: /bin/bash -c exec phantomjs --load-images=no --ignore-ssl-errors=yes /tmp/meteor_2576971355
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:200:12)
at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:862:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:222:5)
stderr:
Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment.
at Object.Meteor.nodeCodeMustBeInFiber (packages/meteor.js:1075:11)
at [object Object]..extend.get (packages/meteor.js:1087:12)
at [object Object].RouteController.lookupOption (packages/iron_router.js:143:29)
at new Controller.extend.constructor (packages/iron_router.js:103:21)
at [object Object].ctor (packages/iron_core.js:144:17)
at Function.Router.createController (packages/iron_router.js:810:18)
at Function.Router.dispatch (packages/iron_router.js:1335:25)
at Object.router (packages/iron_router.js:624:12)
at next (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/webapp/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:174:15)
at Object.handle (packages/cfs_http-methods.js:444:12)`

Answer (score 0):

Spiderable works fine when I deploy build with "debug: true" option in mup.js file under buildOptions section. Strange!
Ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mup#build-options